# Convert a .log file to Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I want to ask about converting a `.log` file into Excel. I have already succeeded in converting the file. But I want to write it in the next column (column B). I already tried using the "\t" function, but it's not working. Here's my code :

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import os,sys
import glob
import keyboard as kb

os.chdir(sys.path[0])
scriptlog = []

for file in glob.glob("*.log"):
    scriptlog.append(file)

tab_char = kb.write("\t")
book = xlwt.Workbook()

for i in scriptlog:
    ws = book.add_sheet(i)
    f = open(i, 'r+')
    data = f.readlines()

    for j in range(len(data)):
        row = data[j].split('\n')

        for k in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(j, k, "\t" + row[k])

book.save('script '+'.xls')
f.close()
```

And here's the result if I use the code above when I copy and paste the cell into the notepad again. The "\t" is going into the same cell and not working as a next column function.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| (tab) text | Cell 2 |
| (tab) text | Cell 4 |

Here's the result that i expected

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Text |
| Cell 3 | Text |